# VPN on RASPBMC on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspbmc, vpn

I am trying to set up a VPN on a Raspberry Pi to connect to VPNBOOK.com

This is proving to be quite problematic. All the guides i have seen online are about setting the Pi up as a VPN Server, i do not want to do this, i just want it to connect to a service.

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

vpnbook.com provides a tutorial :
http://www.vpnbook.com/howto/setup-openvpn-on-ubuntu

This one is for ubuntu but will most likely work with raspbmc.

Just grab a terminal and follow the instructions.

Comment: While this might be an answer to the question, please consider including the most relevant part in the answer linked to here on the site. This to prevent future link-rot. Thank you.